# Allowing the SoundCloud player to appear in a post excerpt

Tags: posts, excerpt

I am setting up a website for my music, in conjunction with my SoundCloud account. I plan to post the links to my soundcloud player as blog posts, but I can't figure out how to make the blog excerpts show the player.

Check out the top post on the site for my example:
http://jonathanperos.com/

I want the post excerpt for "Honeycomb Rainbow" show the player for it.

Answer (score 1):

The excerpt will only fetch the text, triming tags. You need to make a new custom field (you can use Advanced Custom Fields) for the ID of that iframe. Then, you need to edit your content_excerpt.php (I don't know wich theme are using) and fetch that field instead or below your excerpt.

For example: (using Advanced Custom field and Twenty Thirteen theme)

```
<?php 
// fetch my custom field call it "player"
$player = get_field('player');
?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
  <div class="entry-summary">
    <h3 class="entry-title">
   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentytwelve' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</h3>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    <iframe src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/<?php echo $player;?>&show_artwork=true&maxwidth=620&maxheight=930&wmode=transparent"></iframe>
  </div>
</article>
```

Hope you understand my english :D

Comment: Is there a way that I can make that custom field called "Soundcloud" as a new post type from the New Posts menu in the admin menus?

Sorry, I'm very much a beginner with code and this is my first time really delving into php.

Comment: Ok, you have 2 options then. I understand you want to have another link in menu in order to have all your soundcloud posts in one place, right? In that case, you need a bigger work. You need to create a new custom post type, and instead of fetch content-excerpt, need to create another template and loop through that posts... It's a little more complicated if you don't ever work with php. My suggestion, search for "advanced custom field" plugin for wordpress, and create that field. Asign to posts (you can use one category) and display the field as I say.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for helping me. I installed Advanced Custom Field and I've been doing my best to get it to do what I want.

I'm having some issues comprehending the plugin. Just to make what I want clear, I put together a quick image for you to show what I'd like to happen. :)

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34206218/Soundcloud%20Website.png